# FormsAuthentication.Decrypt

Tags: .net, encryption, forms-authentication, hmacsha1

I need to replicate the work done by FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() by calling the relevant System.Security.Cryptography class myself.

I understand that if I haven't specified the encryption type in the web.config (machineKey) FormsAuthentication.Encrypt() defaults to SHA1, which uses the HMACSHA1 algorithm.

Source: [What encryption method does the .NET FormsAuthentication.Encrypt() method use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642598/what-encryption-method-does-the-net-formsauthentication-encrypt-method-use)

-

But if HMACSHA1 is a one way algorithm, how is this possible?

Source: [How to decrypt a string encrypted with HMACSHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434154/how-to-decrypt-a-string-encrypted-with-hmacsha1)

Comment: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Security/FormsAuthentication@cs/2/FormsAuthentication@cs

Comment: cookieAuthParseTicket() seems to do the decrypting... the code for this isn't available as far as I am aware. How are Microsoft doing the decryption if this is one-way?

Comment: This link suggests they are (somehow) but I won't be able to find out what Microsoft's implementation is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587450/how-to-get-at-contents-of-forms-authentication-ticket-with-php